# Ember-CLI Resolver: Class/Sub-class Naming Convention

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Based on my understanding so far of the Ember-CLI / ES6 Resolver, please help me clarify the correct way to define a class and corresponding sub-class for an object.

---

### Assuming I have an Ember.Object:

**file name:** `orange-widget.js`

```
export default Ember.Object.extend({
    //Code
});
```

---

**Is it possible to define a sub-class of that only by referencing it in the first line?**

e.g. `cool-orange-widget.js`

```
export default Ember.OrangeWidget.extend({
    //New Code
});
```

---

**Or do I need to *export* `OrangeWidget` class and then *import* it into the sub-class?**

```
var OrangeWidget = Ember.Object.extend({
    //Code
});

export default OrangeWidget;
```

...then

```
import OrangeWidget from 'orange-widget';

var CoolOrangeWidget = Ember.OrangeWidget.extend({
    //Code
});

export default CoolOrangeWidget;
```

---

Which is the correct method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import your base class into a variable and extend from that.

```
import OrangeWidget from 'orange-widget';

var CoolOrangeWidget = OrangeWidget.extend({
    //Code
});

export default CoolOrangeWidget;
```

Comment: Ok good, I knew I was close.  So in this case it doesn't really matter what the actual file name is... only the variable that is exported correct?

Comment: The syntax is import <variable> from <filename>. There are other syntax options. You may need to read a bit more into es6 modules.